# unproject does not work as intended for object picking if camera moves

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, orthographic

I'm trying to implement object picking system and so far it works if I don't move my camera.

If I don't move camera it shows mouse position correctly in world coordinates. I can't capture the mouse in my screenshot but it's inside the white "circle" and the coordinates are on the top left corner in the image.

[image]

But if I move the camera down a bit, it continues to show (0, 0) at the center of the screen again.

[image]

What I want and expect it to be is (0, -5) or something.

Here is my code:

```
double mouse_x, mouse_y;
glfwGetCursorPos(window, &mouse_x, &mouse_y);
vec3 mouse_pos = vec3(float(mouse_x), float(mouse_y), 0.0f);
world_mouse_pos = unProject(mouse_pos, view, projection, vec4(0, 0, window_width, window_height));

mouse_offset.x = last_mouse_pos.x - world_mouse_pos.x;
mouse_offset.y = last_mouse_pos.y - world_mouse_pos.y;

last_mouse_pos.x = world_mouse_pos.x;
last_mouse_pos.y = world_mouse_pos.y;

m_state = glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_MIDDLE);
if (m_state == GLFW_PRESS){
    view = translate(view, vec3(-mouse_offset, 0.0f));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(view_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, &view.data[0][0]);
}
```

unProject function:

```
inline vec3 unProject(const vec3 &pos, const mat4 &modelview, const mat4 &proj, const vec4 &viewport){
     mat4 inv = inverse(proj * modelview);
     vec4 temp = vec4(pos, 1.0f);
     temp.x = ((temp.x - viewport.x) / viewport.z);
     temp.y = ((temp.y - viewport.y) / viewport.w);
     temp = temp * 2 - 1;
     temp.y = - temp.y; 

     vec4 obj = inv * temp;

     return vec3(obj.x, obj.y, obj.z);
}
```

I am using an orthographic projection. Basically unProject is always returning the same values despite the camera being in another position.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If others have the same problem, I figured it out. So I forgot that my matrices are row major so my unProject function was wrong, here is the correct function:

```
inline vec3 unProject(const vec3 &pos, const mat4 &modelview, const mat4 &proj, const vec4 &viewport){
    mat4 inv = inverse(modelview * proj);

    vec4 temp = vec4(pos, 1.0f);
    temp.x = ((temp.x - viewport.x) / viewport.z);
    temp.y = ((temp.y - viewport.y) / viewport.w);
    temp = temp * 2 - 1;
    temp.y = -temp.y;

    vec4 obj = transpose(inv) * temp;

    obj /= obj.w;

    return vec3(obj.x, obj.y, obj.z);
}
```

Basically I changed the order of the first multiplication and transpose the inverse matrix to be able to multiply it by a vec4. I also divided the final vec4 obj by obj.w, just to be more general-purpose function and work in a Perspective projection, it makes no difference in orthographic projection.
I also made small changes to the other code.

```
double mouse_x, mouse_y;
glfwGetCursorPos(window, &mouse_x, &mouse_y);
vec3 mouse_pos = vec3(float(mouse_x), float(mouse_y), 0.0f);
world_mouse_pos = unProject(mouse_pos, view, projection, vec4(0, 0, window_width, window_height));

mouse_offset.x = last_mouse_pos.x - world_mouse_pos.x;
mouse_offset.y = last_mouse_pos.y - world_mouse_pos.y;

last_mouse_pos.x = world_mouse_pos.x;
last_mouse_pos.y = world_mouse_pos.y;
mouse_offset = -mouse_offset;

m_state = glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_MIDDLE);
if (m_state == GLFW_PRESS){
    view = translate(view, vec3(mouse_offset*0.5, 0.0f));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(view_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, &view.data[0][0]);
}
```

I multiply mouse_offset by -1 to have inverted controls, which is just a preference, but I also multiply it by 0.5, which is basically the velocity of panning the camera.

Comment: This `unProject` code doesn't return the values I'm expecting, are you sure i's correct?